# Already executing in supervisor mode; how to start user mode? (several scenarios)

Tags: assembly, 68000, supervisor-mode

I've been doing some extra homework from my textbook to prepare for my 68000 Assembly exam coming up in the next few weeks. There are currently 4 questions which ask how the user mode can be started while already being executed in supervisor mode. I know that the instructions **EOR**, **ANDI**, and **MOVE** will let me do this, but I was wondering if the following examples are valid to start user mode:

```
EOR D0,SR        ;SR is status register (is this the right way to address the SR?)

ANDI #1,SR       ;Starting user via ANDI

MOVEI, #1,SR     ;Starting user via MOVEI
```

Are the above three instructions valid to start the user mode while already in supervisor mode?

My final question has to do with the trace mode. I am completely lost with this one and I need a little guidance. Here is the question:

**Illustrate how a user program at address $4000 can be started in trace mode with an interrupt mask level of 5.**

If I could get any tips I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, the good old days of 68000 programming.  I remember typing `move.w #$2700,sr` like it was yesterday.

You are on the right track.  `EORI`, `ANDI`, and `MOVEI` can all modify the status register.  Your attempt to use the immediate value `#1` is wrong, however.

One of these ought to work:

```
eori #$2000,sr
andi #$dfff,sr
move #$2000,sr  ;Depends on what interrupt level you want.
```

As for the second part of your question, a hint is:

```
move #$8500,sr
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll mess around with the interrupt mask and see if I can make sense of it. Thanks for the help!